# If the prime interest rate goes up, then it is sufficient that unemployment goes down for prices to rise

Tags: propositional-calculus

I need an appropriate proposition for the following statement:

> If the prime interest rate goes up, then it is sufficient that unemployment goes down for prices to rise.

With $p=$ prime interest rate goes up, $q=$ unemployment goes down and $r=$ prices rise, I am confused as to whether the above statement would be written as
$$p\implies(q\implies r)$$
or
$$p\implies(q\land r)$$

also

> unemployment goes down only if the prime interest rate goes up.

would this not be the same as

$$q\implies p$$

Comment: The first interpretation is the correct one.

Comment: Okay thanks a lot, so it would actually be

$$p\implies(q\implies r)$$

Comment: The first is correct; as for your second one, that is correct also.

Comment: Thanks a lot, although one small question would that be also the same as

$$(p\implies(q))$$
$$(q\implies(r))$$
Therefore
$$(p\implies(r))$$